# Sheet to Sheet Data Transfer with one constant in each sheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a regional store manager that needs help in Excel. We will be comparing regional ranks within the national ranks.

There are two sheets in the workbook.

Sheet 1 columns A-C: RANK | National Store IDs | SALES (largest to smallest)

Sheet 2 columns A-E: Regional Store IDs | Location | Manager | SALES | RANK

Sheet 2 will have manually input set data: Regional Store ID, Location, and manager

What I would like to accomplish is for sheet 2 to automatically enter the SALES from sheet1 column-C to SALES sheet2 column-D and national rank from sheet1 Column-A to sheet2 column-E. The constant in the both sheets will be the Store ID; which is set in column-A sheet2 per row and random in sheet1 column-B.

Is there a simple click to do this or does it require some programming?

Comment: Don't put sample data into comments. Edit your post and put it in the post.

Comment: google spreadsheet tag removed, sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On sheet 2 use this formula in cell D2 to get the sales.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

In E2 use this to get the rank

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

Copy down.